# How can I withdraw ether balance from contract to a personal account?

Tags: solidity, ether, ropsten

How can I withdraw ether balance from a contract to a personal account? İ tried but I couldn't do it on Ropsten. Could anybody tell me step by step how to test this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, contracts **can** hold ether balance. To withdraw funds, you just need to do:

```
msg.sender.transfer(balance);
```

Where `msg.sender` is the external account which calls the contract's function. You can find an example escrow contract written in Solidity [here](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol).